# How to call internal route?

Tags: php, slim

Suppose I declared an `API` route for `/test` inside a file called `foo.php`, how can I access this route `/test` from another file?

Example (foo.php):

```
$app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{

});
```

I want access to this route from `test.php`, how can I do that?

Comment: Rewrite that as separate class that you can inject into any classes that need it

Comment: There is no method called `test` in your code (only a `/test` route) and it's unclear what you mean by saying `access to the method test`, the word `access` is not fully clear in this context. Please clarify these so the readers can help.

Comment: @Nima yep sorry, instead of method I mean "route"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having one very large `foo.php` file, there are several smaller files that make building a larger application much easier.

**test.php**

```
$app = new Slim();

require 'foo.php';

$app->run();
```

**foo.php**

```
$app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
    return 'Hello World!';
});
```

[How to organize a large Slim Framework application](https://www.slimframework.com/2011/09/24/how-to-organize-a-large-slim-framework-application.html)